# Can I refer someone without committing?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, area-51, referrals

One of the proposals (specifically the [Food and Cooking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking) proposal) is a perfect site for a friend of mine, but not so much for me. Can I send her a referal request without having committed myself?

If not is this a deliberate choice or just a not-implemented feature?

Comment: I totally agree with you Mark. It's pointless to force me to commit to something I have no interest in. But why wouldn't they want me to suggest it to a friend who I know is an expert and would love to participate? Bizzare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Share This" link is now present on *all* Area 51 proposals...

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I disagree with [Ivo's reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54690/can-i-refer-someone-without-committing/54703#54703).

I know a group of tinkerers who'd be a *perfect* fit for launching-today [Electronic and Robotics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2651?phase=commitment), for example, but I myself just lack have the know-how.

It'd be great to get at least some form of acknowledgment. It's not like reputation abunds on Area51 anyway -- in over five months there still are no 10k mods.

Comment: But what's the value of having rep on Area51 anyway?

Comment: @Ivo: hardly any, which is pretty much the point :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's deliberate. The point is to **create a community**, if you're not part of it then you can't help building it.

How would you benefit from him/her committing to the site if you don't do it yourself? Just send them the link and they can commit for themselves.

Comment: That's true. I suppose my argument is that referals are unarguably good for StackExchange and so should be encouraged with reputation.

Comment: Only if the referred person actually commits, else you should be punished ;-) It's not just about the size of the community!