# Being able to share a Q&A proposal without being involved

Tags: feature-request, area-51, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I refer someone without committing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54690/can-i-refer-someone-without-committing)

I think that the "Share this" link should always be displayed on an Area51 proposal.

Actually, it is only displayed if you're involved in a proposal (commited...).
But today I've a proposal that could be interesting some friends and I wanted to share the link on facebook. But couldn't find it and I had to put the link manually.

Don't get me wrong this is not reeeaaally hard to do that. But as the feature already exist, I think that it could help to always display it.

Comment: The generated link contains your referral information, as you didn't commit, you don't have one

Comment: @Juan Yes I thought of that but in that case as I'm not involved in the proposal, I would say I don't care of the referral. If there is no referral to set, just share the link "as is".

Answer (score 2):

Go to the definition phase of that proposal, click follow, share, unfollow

Comment: Hum... yes it's quite like copying the link and sharing it... but using a workaround.
As this is possible, it may be possible to always display it.

Comment: This is useful if you're aware you can do this. I think with all the extra space there is on the page, it would be beneficial to say "Know someone who would be interested in this proposal? Share it!" I know this is a year old, but I really like this idea.