# How to refer a friend to a StackExchange proposal?

Tags: feature-request, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I refer someone without committing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54690/can-i-refer-someone-without-committing)

It seems like the only way to refer a friend to a proposal it to commit to it, refer the friend, then uncommit to it. Seems a bit daft. Am I missing something?

Comment: So you want to get the bonuses for referring people but without committing yourself? I think that's a feature request, not a bug.

Comment: It's a fine line between the two.

Comment: It suffices to follow [to get those links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57136/being-able-to-share-a-qa-proposal-without-being-involved/57206#57206). If you also want to help a proposal, it's better to use the referral link of someone who did commit. (In your case, I'll blatantly advertise [Physics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics?referrer=Ho2q28uHijgN5QfMOt5KEg2) :)

Answer (score 2):

During the commitment phase, you should be evangelizing the site proposal, and referring others via the widgets we provide.

[image]

There should be a commitment sharing link as pictured -- assuming you've committed yourself.

You want to share commitment *without* committing yourself? Then just copy paste the URL to the commitment page, I suppose..?

Comment: What I'm saying is that there isn't a widget to refer people, unless you yourself commit. I don't personally want to commit to the Physics SE, but I know my Dad would be very interested. He's *exactly the sort of person they want*. If it makes sense to reward referrals, then it should still make sense if I don't personally commit. Look, I'm not trying to game the system, I trying to help.

Comment: @rocket the way the system is designed, commits are only tracked if you yourself are committed. I recommend simply **sharing the URL** to any proposal you think others might be interested in.

Comment: But why not encourage and reward people for referring others? If it's worth rewarding for a commited user, then it should also be worth rewarding an uncommited user.